# Why isn't my code entering the for-loop in C?

Tags: c, loops, hpc

I'm struggling with a parallel program in C as I can't get my code to enter a for-loop. I have the section

```
int section_start = (row_ind == 0) ? 1 : row_ind;
int section_end = (row_ind == NXPROB - numrows) ? section_start + numrows - 2 : section_start + numrows - 1;

printf("Worker %d had section start %d and section end %d \n", taskid, section_start, section_end);
printf("parms.nts = %d \n", parms.nts);

for (int it = 1; it <= parms.nts; it++) {
   printf("I got in");
}
```

I know that `parms.nts` gives me the correct value, in this case 1000. So I was just wondering is there any reason why my code isn't entering this loop? Is the problem actually with the loop or is it some other problem that is manifesting itself here?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: maybe the prinf is just not flushing, so if `printf("I got in\n");` works, then that might be the issue

Comment: There's no apparent error here, so the problem may be elsewhere.  Please update your question with a [mcve] that others can run *as is*.

Comment: @PeterT that worked! Thanks so much! I would never had known that was an issue!